# SearchView on ActionBar ignores theme setting of containing window

Tags: android, themes, appcelerator, searchview

I'm trying to style a SearchView in an ActionBar.
I created a style specifically for the view that has the SearchView but even if I set the style on creation of the window with

```
 "#windowid[platform=android]":{
     theme:'customTheme'
 }
```

the SearchView actually ignores it. All the other elements of the window are correcly coloured besides the SearchView.

Any workaround?

Thanks
Alex

**EDIT TO PROVIDE MORE INFORMATIONS:**

This is the code in js file where I add the SearchView

```
    var search = Ti.UI.Android.createSearchView({
    hintText: args.hintText,
    iconifiedByDefault:false,
    iconified:false,
    //backgroundColor:'white'
    width:Ti.UI.FILL,
    softKeyboardOnFocus:Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS
});
$.ricercaFermata.softKeyboardOnFocus=Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS;
$.ricercaFermata.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
    var abx = require('com.alcoapps.actionbarextras');
    var actionBar = e.source.activity.actionBar;
    if (actionBar) {
        actionBar.displayHomeAsUp = true;
        actionBar.onHomeIconItemSelected = function () {
            chiudi();
        };
    }
    e.source.activity.onCreateOptionsMenu = function(ev) { 
        var menu = ev.menu; 
        Ti.API.info('this menu '+menu);
        var menuItem = menu.add({ 
            title : "Cerca",
            actionView:search,
            showAsAction : Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
        });
        abx.setSearchView({ 
          searchView: search, 
          backgroundColor: Alloy.CFG.colorePrincipale,
          textColor: 'white',
          hintColor: 'white',
        });
    };
    e.source.activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
});
```

In tss file I use the code I posted before to indicate the correct theme.

This is the custom_theme.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="checkTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#F2660D</item>
    <!--<item name="colorPrimary">#00517D</item>-->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00517D</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#F2660D</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#F2660D</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#F2660D</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#F2660D</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#00517D</item>
     <item name="android:buttonTint">#00517D</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>-->
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <!--<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#F2660D</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <!--<item name="textColorPrimary">#1565C0</item>-->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextApearance</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/test</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Widget.EditText.Color</item>
    <!--<item name="android:searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>-->
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyTimePickerDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <!--<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBox</item>-->
</style>
<style name="materialTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#00517D</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00517D</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#F2660D</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#F2660D</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#F2660D</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#00517D</item>
     <item name="android:buttonTint">#00517D</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>-->
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <!--<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#F2660D</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <!--<item name="textColorPrimary">#1565C0</item>-->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextApearance</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/test</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Myactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Widget.EditText.Color</item>
    <!--<item name="android:searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>-->
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyTimePickerDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <!--<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBox</item>-->
</style>
<style name="CheckBox" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/checkbox_bg</item>
     <item name="android:button">@drawable/checkbox_custom_states</item>-->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#F2660D</item>
</style>
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTimePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#00517D</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/MyTimePickerStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:calendarTextColor">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">#F2660D</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
    <item name="android:minDate">01/01/2000</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTimePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:calendarTextColor">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">#00517D</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="test" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:progressTint">#F2660D</item>
</style>

<style name="Myactionbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
<style name="myCustomMenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.EditText.Color" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00517D</item>
</style>
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#00517D</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00517D</item>
    <!--<item name="android:background">#5fa3d0</item>-->
</style>
</resources>
```

Basically, the main theme is materialTheme, I use checkTheme to color the checkboxes for android 4 devices when not selected (or they appear white).

With materialTheme, the magnifier icon in SearchView is white, but if I set as main theme checkTheme the magnifier becomes orange.
If I change the theme for the window with the SearchView in materialTheme, the magnifier remain orange, and does not become white as expected.

I hope to have explained at best the problem, thanks!